# html - display a picture which is dependant on the result I get from a query call

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Good day,

I hope my question will be clear enough. Sorry for bothering you as I don't know really where to start and what exactly I should be looking for.

What I currently have is a picture displayed as follows in an html page :

```
<div id="tag_sunrise_sunset"><p><img src="assets/icons/sun_icon.png" alt="" width="14" height="14">&#8593; 06:25 &#8595; 20:33</p></div>
```

Next to that, I am calling the function below each 1/2 second :

```
/******************************************
* Gets the latest data from the database
******************************************/
// Global variables
var AutoScript = false;
var ValueCheck = -1;
var ControleurUpdate = "";      
var ThermostatManualUpdate = false; 
var DebugMode = false;



function getDataFromDatabase(j)
{ 
    var complete = false;
    var json=$.parseJSON(j);
    var techname = "";
    var techname1 = "";
    var valuetf;
    var typecomp;
    var value01;
    var c;
    var w;

    $(json).each(function(i,val){
    $.each(val,function(k,v){

    if (DebugMode)
    {
        console.log ("k = " + k);
        console.log ("v = " + v);
        console.log ("----------------");
    }

    switch (k)
    {
        case "tech_name":
        techname = v;
        techname1 = "#" + v;
        break;

        case "value_t_f":
        valuetf = v;
        break;

        case "compo_type":
        typecomp = parseInt(v);
        complete = true;
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }

    if (complete)
    {
        if (DebugMode)
        {
            console.log ("Mon nom est " + techname + " (" + techname1 + ")" + " Je suis de type " + typecomp + " et ma valeur est " + valuetf);
        }
        complete = false;               // Pour être sur que l'on peut revenir plus tard dans cette boucle!

        // Types de composants              
        // NB : simplified structure of the if statements [check ? value_if_true : value_if_false;]
        c=document.getElementById(techname);

        if (c===null)           // Check that the components exists
        {
            if (DebugMode)
            {
                console.log("Component " + techname + " does not exist");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (typecomp)
            {
                case 1:         // lumière 1 relais
                case 2:         // lumière 2 relais
                    (valuetf > 0) ? value01 = 1 : value01 = 0;                      
                    (c.checked) ? w = 1 : w = 0;

                    if (value01 != w)
                    {               
                    // Pas identique -> besoin d'un traitement

                    (value01 == 0) ? uncheckBox(techname1) : checkBox(techname1);
                    }
                break;

                case 3:         // lumière variateur
                break;

                case 4:         // prise multiple
                break;

                case 5:         // store
                break;

                case 6:         // thermostat
                var ctrl = techname;
                document.getElementById(ctrl).value = valuetf;

                c=document.getElementById("prg01");
                c.value = valuetf;
                break;

                case 7:          // alarme
                break;

                default:
                console.log("autre");
                break;
        }
    }
    }
    });
    });
}
```

What I would like is that depending on the result of the variable 'w', I could display a different picture. Is there an easy way to achieve this, or is Ajax not designed at all for this purpose ?

Sorry if the question may sound silly, but I am kind of stuck. Also, I am sure that my code has (a lot of) room for improvement, but please be indulgent as it is my first try in the CSS/HTML/Javascript world.

I thank you very much for your time and your help.

Comment: I think you are confused about what ajax is, there is no ajax related code in the code you posted. If you want to change an image src, you can do it with jquery like  $('img', '#tag_sunrise_sunset').attr('src', 'images/alt/imagename.jpg');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several approaches to this, depending on what you want to do exactly.
You could absolutely send an AJAX request that retrieves the URL of an image, then you simply set the src attribute of your image to the new URL.
But perhaps in this case it would be easier if, seeing as how there can only be 2 states for 'w', you put both images into your HTML, and simply toggle their visibility with Javascript. This would make the result more instantaneous.